# Bullets in list following mouse movement

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I've been having a problem I've been working on for multiple hours now with no luck. I have movement bound to arrow keys and the user looks around via the mouse. When I shoot I want it to continue off in the direction it initially started, but what happens is if the user moves the mouse the bullets change directions with it.

```
var myTimer2:Timer = new Timer(50);
var list:Array = new Array();

myTimer2.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener2);
myTimer2.start();

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shoot);
function shoot(shooteven:Event)
{
    var Create:Bullet = new Bullet();
    addChild(Create);
    Create.x = player_obj.x;
    Create.y = player_obj.y;
    list.push(Create);
}

function timerListener2(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    moveBullets();
}

function moveBullets():void
{
    var target:Bullet;
    for (var i:int=0; i<list.length; i++)
    {
        target = Bullet(list[i]);
        target.currentPlayerRotation = player_obj.rotation;
        target.x +=Math.cos((target.currentPlayerRotation)*degreesToRadians) *10;
        target.y +=Math.sin((target.currentPlayerRotation)*degreesToRadians) *10;
    }
}
```

And this is the code that I use at the start for the "player" to follow the cursor.

```
stage.addEventListener("mouseMove", Follow);
function Follow(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var a1 = mouseY - player_obj.y;
    var b1 = mouseX - player_obj.x;
    var radians1 = Math.atan2(a1,b1);
    var degrees1 = radians1 / (Math.PI / 180);
    player_obj.rotation = degrees1;
}
```

I think what is causing the problem is that when I push the bullets into the array they're all sharing the effects of the user moving the mouse instead of keeping their initial value. If anyone has any input on this it would be greatly appriciated and sorry for the long post.

Thanks,
Cole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that code:

```
var myTimer2:Timer = new Timer(50);
var list:Array = new Array();

myTimer2.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener2);
myTimer2.start();

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shoot);
function shoot(shooteven:Event)
{
    var Create:Bullet = new Bullet();
    addChild(Create);
    Create.x = player_obj.x;
    Create.y = player_obj.y;
    Create.currentPlayerRotation = player_obj.rotation;
    list.push(Create);
}

function timerListener2(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    moveBullets();
}

function moveBullets():void
{
    var target:Bullet;
    for (var i:int=0; i<list.length; i++)
    {
        target = Bullet(list[i]);
        target.x +=Math.cos((target.currentPlayerRotation)*degreesToRadians) *10;
        target.y +=Math.sin((target.currentPlayerRotation)*degreesToRadians) *10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had situations like this one before. The best solution I could find was to add two properties to the projectile class to store the sine and cosine of the initial angle. If the speed of the projectile never changes, you can very well save the deltaX and deltaY for the projectile instead. You would not need the Bullets' "currentPlayerRotation" propery anymore.

your shoot function would look like this:

```
function shoot(shooteven:Event)
{
  var Create:Bullet = new Bullet();
  addChild(Create);
  Create.x = player_obj.x;
  Create.y = player_obj.y;
  Create.dirCos = Math.cos((player_obj.rotation)*degreesToRadians);
  Create.dirSin = Math.sin((player_obj.rotation)*degreesToRadians);
  list.push(Create);
}
```

the loop that moves your bullets is simplified too, now that there is no sin()/cos() call for every projectile on the screen.

```
for (var i:int=0; i<list.length; i++)
{
  target = Bullet(list[i]);
  target.x += target.dirCos * 10;
  target.y += target.dirSin * 10;
}
```

I hope this helps you out.